# How can I get my Audio on my start function to be on a loop so that it plays the whole time during gameplay in javascript?

Tags: javascript, background-music

I am trying to get myMusic that is pulled from my .html file to run on a loop after the start game function is ran and I can't figure out how to do it. I figure there has to be something I can do in the startgame function to the myMusic.play(); but I can't figure it out. any help would be appreciated.

```js
var myMusic = document.getElementById("myMusic");
var myStartSound = document.getElementById("myStartSound");
var myWinSound = document.getElementById("myWinSound");
var myLoseSound = document.getElementById("myLoseSound");
var themeMusic = document.getElementById("themeMusic");
var audio = new Audio("./assets/Sounds/Halo theme.mp3");
window.onload = function(){
    audio.play()
    .then(function () {
        console.log("ahhhhh");

    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        audio.currentTime = 1;
        audio.play()
        .then(function () {
            console.log("ahhhhh");
    
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            audio.currentTime = 1;
            audio.play()
        })
    })

}

//alphabet array
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
    'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
];

//array for users guessed letters
var guessedLetter = [];
//array for users correct guesses
var correctLetter = [];
//guessed letters that are incorrect
var incorrectGuess = [];



//Below is the functionality of the game
function startGame() {
    numGuesses = 12;
    blanksAndSuccess = [];
    guessedLetter = [];
    incorrectGuess = [];
    audio.pause();
    myMusic.play()
        .then(function () {
            console.log("ahhhhh");

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing

`document.getElementById("myMusic").loop = true;`

According to [w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_loop.asp):

> The loop property sets or returns whether an audio should start playing over 
>   again when it is finished.
>
> This property reflects the  loop attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that the audio should start playing over
>   again when it is finished.

Meaning that this should make your audio go on loop mode

Answer (score 0):

There is an extremely easy way to do it, both in HTML and Javascript.
HTML:

```
    <audio src = "" loop = true>
```

Javascript:

```
    document.getElementById("audio").loop = true;
```

I also integrated it into a function that plays music, and you can choose to loop it:

```
    var makePlayAudio = function(src, looping) {
        var aud = new Audio();
        aud.src = src;
        aud.loop = looping;
        aud.play();
    }
```

I have tested it on chrome.